# How to test code with Git and GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a private Git repository set up on GitHub with a master branch. I've been fiddling with tutorials and articles for too long trying to figure out how to test code locally before committing changes to the live site (I have a feeling it's not as complicated as my frustration is trying to tell me).

**Simply put**: How do I create a local folder of files identical to the master branch or a branch where I can edit, update, debug and change code (without affecting the master branch and live site), then, when ready, commit the changes to the master branch? It seems like a simple flow, but I'm not experienced with Git. I'm using GitHub Desktop right now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a local copy of the project?
If yes, then you have to just `git clone <github-link>`  to get the project to your local system and edit/update it.

Comment: Is this connected to the same remote origin? What if I wanted to commit a change?

Comment: My project is already local ... that's how I created my GitHub repository (dragging a folder of files into GitHub desktop and making private repository)

Comment: you'd commit to your local repo and `git push` to your origin, which I think is set together when you use `git clone`

Comment: The issue is that when I edit the files, the site is live, it changes with my edits ... I'd like a way to test the updates before the live site displays them

Comment: How do I commit to my local repo?

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you cloned it the right way. There must be a clone option in Github Desktop. To commit a change you have to `git add <filename>` , `git commit` then `git push`

Comment: Is it because I'm editing locally I'm instantly seeing the changes? I don't have an external computer to test if my changes are being added yet to the master branch ... is that how it works? I make changes and I see them because the folder is local, but until I commit the changes to the remote origin master branch, the site on computers other than my local computer with the site files / clone isn't yet updated?

Comment: If you are editing the files locally and running your project from your local system, then you will see the changes. Unless you do a `git push` the changes wont be pushed to the master branch

Answer (score 0):

> Simply put: How do I create a local folder of files identical to the master branch or a branch where I can edit, update, debug and change code (without affecting the master branch and live site)

```
# checkout new branch based upon the current branch 
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

---

> If I create a new branch, do I have to copy that files; Or are they copied automatically if I create a new branch?

The new branch is a **FULL** copy to the current branch.
In order to understand why you need to know what is branch in git.

---

#### What is branch in GIT?

A branch in Git is simply a **lightweight movable** pointer to commit.
[Here](https://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/stepup/stepup1_1.html) is a very short and simple post about it

#### In other words:

Branch in git is simply a pointer to a commit.
As you can see in the image below (taken from the post mentioned above), all the branches are pointing to commit B + the delta which was added to them.

When you create branch git creates a file and writing the commit id to this file.

[image]

> When I want work on the branch, do I have to switch to that branch inside GIT, before I start to work (opening that files)?

This is what's the checkout -b does - switch you to the new branch
[image]